# You don’t have enough space error

Tags: upgrade

When I want to run “sudo apt upgrade”, this error shows up:

```
You don’t have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives.
```

Then, I run this code:

```
sudo apt autoclean
```

and also

```
sudo apt clean
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

However, nothing changes and the same error appears again when upgrading.

Comment: try to write `sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/*` to see the error

Comment: @BNoor What is the output of `df -H`?

Comment: There will be no error when running sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/*. But it won’t change anything.